# using es6 reduce() to manipulate an object using another object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have state object as:

```
this.state = {
    letterType: {},
    letterTag: {},
    departmentName: {},
    assignedOfficer: {}
}
```

and I have an another object `sortFilters` as:

```
sortFilters = {
    letterType: {
        0: "letterType1",
        1: "letterType2"
    },
    letterTag: {},
    departmentName: {
        0: "dept1"
    },
    assignedOfficer: {}
}
```

now what I want is to create a newState object (probably using es6 `reduce()`) which will be created based on `sortFilters` object such as:

```
this.newState = {
    letterType: {
        letterType1: true,
        letterType2: true
    },
    letterTag: {},
    departmentName: {
        dept1: true
    },
    assignedOfficer: {}
}
```

I think this is possible using es6 reduce() but I am not able to get it to work.

Comment: `reduce` isn't "ES6" (it was in ES5, ~2009). And it's for arrays, not non-array objects.

Comment: `I am not able to get it to work` with no code, it's no surprise

Answer (score 0):

As described, your problem is a use case for [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), since you just want to copy the contents of four objects (on `sortFilters`) into your state object. You'd either do it manually:

```
Object.assign(this.newState.letterType,      sortFilters.letterType);
Object.assign(this.newState.letterTag,       sortFilters.letterTag);
Object.assign(this.newState.departmentName,  sortFilters.departmentName);
Object.assign(this.newState.assignedOfficer, sortFilters.assignedOfficer);
```

...or in a loop:

```
for (const name of Object.keys(sortFilters)) {
    Object.assign(this.newState[name], sortFilters[name]);
}
```

That **merges** the entries from the `sortFilters` objects with the ones in `this.newState`. If you want to *replace* them instead, you'd use assignment (and probably a shallow copy, but that depends on how `sortFilters` is used later):

```
this.newState.letterType      = Object.assign({}, sortFilters.letterType);
this.newState.letterTag       = Object.assign({}, sortFilters.letterTag);
this.newState.departmentName  = Object.assign({}, sortFilters.departmentName);
this.newState.assignedOfficer = Object.assign({}, sortFilters.assignedOfficer);
```

or

```
for (const name of Object.keys(sortFilters)) {
    this.newState[name] = Object.assign({}, sortFilters[name]);
}
```

Note that `Object.assign` does a *shallow* copy; if any of these objects are nested, you'll need something else.

As of ES2018, you can use property spread when creating the new objets instead of `Object.assign`:

```
for (const name of Object.keys(sortFilters)) {
    this.newState[name] = {...sortFilters[name]};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other methods to achieve the same, as `reduce` is used over arrays. But if using `reduce` is a practice, then Yes that is also possible, a rough way could be like the following, where we can use `reduce` over keys of objects, which is an array.

```js
let state = {letterType: {},letterTag: {},departmentName: {},assignedOfficer: {}}

let sortFilters = {letterType: {0: "letterType1",1: "letterType2"},letterTag: {},departmentName: {0: "dept1"},assignedOfficer: {}}

let newState = Object.keys(state).reduce(function(prev, current) {
  let val = sortFilters[current]
  if (!val) {
    prev[current] = state[current]
  } else {
    prev[current] = Object.keys(val).reduce(function (p, c) {
      p[val[c]] = true
      return p
    }, {})
  }
  return prev
}, {})

console.log(newState)
```

For more details about [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), please refer to Mozilla Developer Network's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what "state" or `this.state` means in this context...React? Anyhow, tt looks like you just want to simply unpack certain properties and manipulate them. If so destructuring assignment might help.  Refer to this article section on [**Destructuring Nested Objects**](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#nested-destructuring) and this section on **[Nested object and array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring)**

---

### Demo

```js
let sortFilters = {
    letterType: {
        0: "letterType1",
        1: "letterType2"
    },
    letterTag: {},
    departmentName: {
        0: "dept1"
    },
    assignedOfficer: {}
}

// Making a copy of sortFilters
let final = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sortFilters));

// Desruturing final, assigning variables and values
let {
   letterType: {
       letterType1: letterType1 = true,
       letterType2: letterType2 = true
   },
   letterTag: {},
    departmentName: {
        dept1: dept1 = true
    },
    assignedOfficer: {}
} = final;

console.log(letterType1);
console.log(letterType2);
console.log(dept1);
```